# How to get code a text overlay and image to be responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I am attempting to re-create something similar to this image below, minus the little page curl in top right hand corner.

Banner Example:

[image: Banner Example]

I am adding the code to a previously coded website by another designer.  I am first coding it separately, but cannot get the text and banner to be responsive, though the image is.  Nor can I get it to overlay like I wish on the image itself.

Here is my code below, I know it is something simple but seem to be hitting a mental wall.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*Header Image*/

.headerimage
 
img 
{
}

h1
{
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 100%;
font-size: 1.45em;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', Rockwell, Serif;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
text-shadow: 0 .125em .125em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
padding: .6em 1em .6em 1.7em;
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(178,34,34,0) 0%,rgba(169,32,32,0.8) 5%,rgba(160,30,30,1) 50%,rgba(152,29,29,0.8) 75%,rgba(178,34,34,0) 100%);
}

.interior-header img
{
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid #b22222;
padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test Heading</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

</head>

<body>


<div class="interior-header img>
<div class="headerimage">

<img src="images/Joslyn-Interior-Images.jpg" width="630" height="240" alt="Traffic Control" />

<h1>Traffic Control</h1>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[Traffic Violations Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3eqP.jpg)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that your chances of getting help would increase if you made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [plunker](http://plnkr.co).

Comment: That is an improvement. However, I think it would be even better as a JSFiddle. (It's hard to test the responsiveness of something in a code snippet.) Futhermore, from the information being given, I can't tell what you want and what's going wrong. Just my two cents. :)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't want to type out all your code so here is an example.

**Note:** When I posted this one, no codes were up, I left it up in case it helps others. The code for the answer is at the bottom of the answer.
https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/5o95L0qy/

```
.box {
background: grey;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
.text {
font-size: 6vw
}
```

**Updated**: Here is the current JsFiddle. Hope this helps.
https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/65wnds86/

Comment: How does this solve the problem? I don't think I understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JefréN. My understanding is she wants the box and text to be responsive.  They are both responsive. Mind you I saw only a pic of the code when I posted this answer.

Comment: Yes sir, that is what I wish to do.  I'm a bit frustrated tonight and have never used the jsfiddle before and cannot seem to get it into my question.  But yes, I'd love for both to be responsive as well as the text overlay to lay correctly over the image itself.

Comment: @VeronicaJones I will recreate your Jsfiddle with your codes, give me a couple of minutes. But what you saw from my previous, text shrinking responsively is indeed what you want?

Comment: @norcaljohnny - 
 
Yes! that is absolutely perfect! The only thing is that I wish to keep the image that is in my code as an actual image and not an image background. Thank you so much, I really aprpeciate it and you've been a super life saver!

Comment: Since the pic does not have the full url I will need to use a fake pic. and then you can replace it.

Comment: @norcaljohnny - That is perfectly fine!  I can easily incorporate my image.  I appreciate this greatly!

Comment: @VeronicaJones check the updated Jsfiddle link above. I kept both just in case the other helps someone. Cheers

Comment: @norcaljohnny - Thank you SO much for all your awesome help!  I just had one more quick question if you don't mind ... the gradient banner background, is there a way for that to be slightly smaller?  Like the height of it?  If so, that would be a great help and would be absolutely perfect!

Comment: What size would you like? We can put a max-width and max-height in the css. You are welcome. :)

Comment: @norcaljohnny - when I add it to the code I am working on, the gradient banner overflows on the right side, so if we put a max-width, will it still be able to be responsive?  And I was thinking something a little more than half the size it is now if possible.

Comment: I added another div to wrap it. Check the update code. You will see where max-width is used. Just adjust it based on the pic you use in your final code.

Comment: @norcaljohnny - I am so sorry if I seem like a huge pain and it means a lot that you've been super patient and kind ... I adjusted with the added code and I seem to have an issue now.  The banner I cannot adjust, when I adjust the max-width, it effects the actual image in the background than the gradient banner =/ -- If we can get this resolved, I promise this is all I need left!

Comment: @VeronicaJones can you add the real image link so I can use the real dimensions? You did see though, 2 max-widths were added?

Comment: @norcaljohnny - Yes sir, I did see those, ty!  When I test in DW, it makes the banner super wide, no matter how I adjust it until I scan the window down.  When I adjust the numbers in the max-width, the background image itself is adjusted.  I added the linked Image in my original post.  Please let me know if you were able to obtain it.  Thank you again!

Comment: @norcaljohnny - Thank you sir!  Is it the same JSfiddle link?  I clicked on https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/65wnds86/ and did not see a change?  Just want to make sure I didn't miss another one lol.

Comment: That is it. I might have not hit update. But it is showing the patrol cars. :) https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/65wnds86/

Comment: @norcaljohnny - I got it !  Thank you SO SO much for ALL your help!  You've been an absolute life saver!

Comment: Glad it all worked out for you. I am not sure if we are allowed to comment here but you are very welcome :)